# Vue-router issue with loading child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an issue.
I have a router like this with child.

```
  {
    component: () => import('@/components/roles/Index'),
    path: '/roles',
    name: 'roles.index',
    meta: {
      auth: true,
      roles: ['admin']
    },
    children: [{
      component: () => import('@/components/roles/Show'),
      path: ':id',
      name: 'roles.show',
      meta: {
        auth: true,
        roles: ['admin']
    }
  }]}
```

When i click on button the url is changing but component is not loading.

```
<v-btn icon class="mx-0" :to="{ name: 'roles.show', params: { id: props.item.id }}">
  <v-icon color="blue">info</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

But when i do this like that everything work right

```
{
  component: () => import('@/components/roles/Index'),
  path: '/roles',
  name: 'roles.index',
  meta: {
    auth: true,
    roles: ['admin']
  }
},
{
  component: () => import('@/components/roles/Show'),
  path: '/roles/:id',
  name: 'roles.show',
  meta: {
    auth: true,
    roles: ['admin']
  }
}
```

Comment: consider posting an actual piece of code, instead of screenshot

Comment: ok i will do this already

Comment: Do you have a `<router-view>` element in your `roles/Index` component? It would help to see the HTML of your components

Comment: No, i will try this. But i have `<router-view>` inside `App.vue`. Project was build with vue-cli

Answer (score 0):

Logically a `path` cannot contain `param` only. `path: ':id'` will match everything, which is problematic.

Comment: oh, I didn't think about it